# Priming a Brett beer (WLP648) for bottling

Tags: priming, sour

I am getting ready to bottle my 6 month old sour. I used WLP648 on primary.

I’ve been reading up on this on other forums, but I get mixed insights: some people say to just go ahead per normal, others pitch additional yeast and some other say you shouldn’t be using regular bottles due to Brett attenuating fast (risking bottle bombs).

Anyone can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

If the brett has completely finished (check with gravity readings), then you're fine to bottle with whatever yeast you like. If you're worried the brett will take too long, bottle with something like T-58. Once all your tricky-to-eat sugars have been fermented, you're past the risk of bottle bombs, unless you introduce a diastatic strain.